# Laravel csrf filter throwing exception before Controller constructor

Tags: php, laravel

So a few of my routes use the csrf filter, which I have added like so:

```
Route::post('/user/notifications/dismiss', array('before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'UsersController@dismiss'));
```

And in my start/global.php I have set up the error handler to produce a view in the production environment (code simplified for this example)

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    if(Config::get('app.debug') === false) {
        return Response::view('message', array('title' => $code, 'message' => 'Server error'));
    }
});
```

In my BaseController __construct() I do some basic init, this includes setting a number of variables to the view

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        $user = Auth::user();
        View::share('user', $user);

        $this->setupAssets();
        $this->setupOtherStuff();
        ...
    }

    // css and js files to include
    protected function setupAssets() {
        $stylesheets = array(
            '/css/styles.css',
        );

        View::share('stylesheets', $stylesheets);

        $javascripts = array(
            '/js/script.js',
        );

        View::share('javascripts', $javascripts);
    }

    ...
```

The problem is that when the application fails the csrf check, it throws an exception in the filter. At this point the BaseController __construct() has not yet run, so I get a bunch of errors that variables used in the view are not assigned.

My question is, what would be the best way of getting around this? I could put all of the view assignments in the App::before() event, but I'd rather avoid doing this as the method could get very big.

Comment: Does the `csrf` filter actually stop the program from continuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course your controller doesn't and shouldn't get called. Instead of changing that, use [view composers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers) to make "global" variables available in your view:

```
View::composer('layout', function($view){
    $view->with('user', Auth::user());
    // and so on...
});
```

You can register your view composers for example in a new file `app/composers.php` and load that in `app/start/global.php` with `require app_path().'/composers.php';`

Comment: Thanks. Though I had to change all of my responses in controllers from View::make() to Response::view() for this to work.

Comment: Really? That seems very odd to me. Any idea why?

Comment: I spoke too soon. It doesn't appear to call the closure before the view is rendered when I use `View::composer('layout', ...`, it only does when I use `View::composer('index', ...` (for example). I'm using blade templates and my index template is extending layout via `@extends('layout')`. I'm guessing this is because the blade engine runs the contents of the `index` view before the `layout`, so the `layout` closure is only run AFTER the `index` has finished rendering. Any idea on how to get around this? Let me know if I'm being unclear.

Comment: I see.. You can make use of `*` wildcards and for example let the composer run for *every* view: `View::composer('*', ...`

Comment: Although, as this runs the composer for every view, it will run it at least twice every page load (one for layout, one for the actual view). Which is less than ideal. I'll continue looking for a way around that.

Comment: That's true. How about you put your code from the base controller into a separate class and call it from your base controllers constructor as well as from a view composer for the `message` vew?

Comment: I ended up doing the wildcard view composer `View::composer('*', 'GlobalComposer');`, but the `GlobalComposer` has a static member flag variable so it will only run once per page load. Feels like I'm abusing the functionality, but it's the solution I'm most comfortable with.